# Android Studio 4.0 Can't resolve gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my first question here so please pardon me if I am doing something wrong lol.

I am trying to build an app in  Android studio 4.0, and I am trying to add this to the gradle file:

```
// Add library
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'
```

However, when I try to sync this, here is the error message I keep getting:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I correct this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Github for MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText), the import statement is incorrect.  It should be:

```
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
```

Comment: Lol, this fixed it completely!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad he was able to solve your issue! Make sure to +1 and **Accept** his answer in order to give him some credit :) Have a nice one and good luck with your project.

Comment: @pmascaraque Thanks for letting me know that,
Cheers!